# Makefile target color output

Tags: linux, bash, colors, makefile

I have written a Makefile which works fine; I do not post it entirely, just the part of it under investigation:

```
COMPILE_cpp = $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $< $(MAKEDEP) $(INCLUDES)

%.o : %.cpp ; $(COMPILE_cpp)
.SUFFIXES: .o .cpp
```

The above code does its duty. Since the build process involves many files I would like to add some color output. I have tried the following

```
PRINT = @echo -e "\e[1;34mBuilding $<\e[0m"

COMPILE_cpp = $(PRINT) && $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $< $(MAKEDEP) $(INCLUDES)

%.o : %.cpp ; $(COMPILE_cpp)
.SUFFIXES: .o .cpp
```

The Makefile still works fine but now I can only see the output of `$(PRINT)` with the chosen color. The command string `$(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $< $(MAKEDEP) $(INCLUDES)` is correctly executed but not printed to screen any more; still I can see the eventual warnings and errors.

I would like to avoid using external tools (such as colorgcc or CMake) and hack it with bash script tricks.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
Just a little add: what about if I want to do something like grep the output of the current built file in order to find strings such as `error` or `warning`?

I would like to highlight them, I was thinking about calling a `sed` on the compiler output to change some words color...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@` symbol at the start of your `PRINT` definition is suppressing the command printing.

Try this:

```
%o : %.cpp
    $(PRINT)
    $(COMPILE_cpp)
```

where $(COMPILE_cpp) is your first version.
Dont forget the tab character indents recipe commands, *not* spaces.

Comment: Thank you 6EQUJ5, it works! Actually I have to take the `@` cause otherwise I get duplicated output (the expected colour print and the string of the command in plain text)

Comment: @helmet_23 You want the `@` on the `print` line. You don't want it on the compile line. The problem was you were combining the two into one command and telling make to hide the command.